# Background top-bar images Zurb Foundation and Flask template inheritance

Tags: flask, zurb-foundation, scss-mixins

I am using [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/) to develop an application. As a front-end framework, I am using [Zurb-Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com). I have created a `layout.html` template and I am using [template inheritance](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/templateinheritance/)  to extend it.

The layout of the website includes a top-bar with a background image, similar to [this one](https://alexzerbach.com/how-to-use-foundation-top-bar-to-overlay-background-image/) . The relevant code for the `layout.html` is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">

<head>
  <!-- More code here -->
</head>    
<body>
  {% block navbar %}
  <header class= {{ headerclass }}>
    <div class="contain-to-grid startup-top-bar">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
        ...
        ...
        ...
  <!-- More code here -->
```

I want to have different top-bar background images for each of the website pages associated with the links on the navigation bar. The top-bar background images depends on `<header class= {{ headerclass }}>`. In order to have different top-bar background images for each of the website pages,  I have parameterized the `<header class= {{ headerclass }}>`. The parameter `{{ headerclass }}` is supplied in the following way:

```
from flask import render_template
from appmodule import app

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', headerclass = 'index')

@app.route("/anotherchild")
def anotherchild():
    return render_template('anotherchild.html', headerclass = 'anotherchild')

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

For example, the `index.html` template that extends `layout.html` is like this:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}Index{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <p class="important">
      Hello world.
    </p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Finally, to generate the `styles.css` I compile some `.scss` files. The relevant code for the one that defines the style for the class `<header class= {{ headerclass }}>` is the following `_main.scss` file:

```
// Style for the index page
.index {
    background: url('../img/img1.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    .startup-hero {
        padding-top: rem-calc(150px);
        padding-bottom: rem-calc(150px);
        .hero-lead {
            color: darken(#fff, 30%);
        }
    }
  ...
  ...
  // more code here

// Style for the anotherchild page
.anotherchild {
    background: url('../img/img2.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    .startup-hero {
        padding-top: rem-calc(150px);
        padding-bottom: rem-calc(150px);
        .hero-lead {
            color: darken(#fff, 30%);
        }
    }
  ...
  ...
  // more code here
```

The good news is that everything is working as expected, but as you might have noticed I am breaking the **DRY** principles in the `_main.scss` file. My question is: Can I use [mixins](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) to solve the issue ? Or what different approach that can be used that is more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue you're having is duplication of styles - just extract these styles to a separate class. Something like this:

```
.header-main {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:  center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    .startup-hero {
        padding-top: rem-calc(150px);
        padding-bottom: rem-calc(150px);
        .hero-lead {
            color: darken(#fff, 30%);
        }
    }


.index {
    background-image: url(../img/img1.JPG);
}
.anotherchild {
    background-image: url(../img/img2.JPG);
}
```

So the markup then simply becomes:

```
<header class="header-main {{ headerclass }}">
```

I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you @dmitrybelyakov If I follow your idea exactly the background image is placed out the right centering. However, If I add more `css` to the particular `{{ headerclass }}` like this ```.index {
 background: url('../img/img1.JPG') no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}``` it works perfectly. Do you have any the reason why it might happens ?

Comment: I think I know why that behavior is happening. According to what I have seen the `.css` code is executed from top to bottom. If that is true, the last code that is executed is ```.index {
    background-image: url(../img/img1.JPG);
}``` but without any style parameters, like `center` , `cover` , etc.  What do you think ?

Comment: `.index` has only the background defined, so it should only add that property to whatever is defined in `.header-main` if you use both classes on the `<header>` element.